# Telegraf Bot API forwarding

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

can anyone suppose what's the reason of such behavior.

The task is to forward message from tg channel (bot has all privilege).
Three upper methods work correctly, but calling the fourth with the same message_id gives the error

> Bad Request: message to forward not found

```
// bot.telegram.deleteMessage('@programmistss', 19)
// bot.telegram.sendMessage('@programmistss', 'just text')
// bot.telegram.editMessageText('@programmistss', 19, 19, 'just text')

bot.telegram.forwardMessage('@nik', '@programmistss', false, 19)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be service message, such as `XXX joined the group`. You can just **ignore** this type of error, or add each situations to blacklist/whitelist.